# how to make sure a port is open on listening and not in use?

Tags: windows, cmd, port, listen

is there a cmd to find out if a port is open on windows for listening and no other processes, users or applications are using it? I have tried net stat commands but I cannot make sure I'm not breaking any other processes by using a port.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat -a` on Windows. The `-b` option will also give you the listening executable name, but it requires elevation (i. e. admin rights).

With `-n` it will work much faster, but the addresses and the protocols will remain numeric.

All options can be specified with `-` or with `/` (e. g. `/a`, `/b`, `/n`, etc). `netstat /?` will dump all command line options. The `/?` option works for most other Windows commands too.

On Linux, the options of `netstat` are different.

Comment: thanks, but how to know which port is not being used by other processes or users?

Comment: The ports that are *not* listed by netstat as listening are not in use :) If your real question is - what port numbers will *never be used* by any process, that question doesn't have an answer, because some programs (notably IIS on Windows) can listen on *any* port, according to its configuration. In practice, if you want to assign a port to your program, just make it configurable, with a default somewhere in thousands.